# security patchup issue SUPEE-6282 and SUPEE-6285 fails to apply

Tags: magento-1.8

I am applying these two patched **SUPEE-6282** and **SUPEE-6285**.

```
PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2015-07-07-09-06-30.sh
```

But my sever support show errors like-

> patching file app/Mage.php Hunk #1 FAILED at 814. 1 out of 1 hunk
>   FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/Mage.php.rej

My server support say that this error is showing due to my custom programming. How can i fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Please anybody can help me ??

Comment: So did you do custom programming in Mage.php ?

Comment: Better asked at http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i did not programming in mage.php

Answer (score 0):

This happen normal when you miss previous patches. Do you have the previous patches installed? If not, you will need to install them before `SUPEE-6282`

I suggest you to upgrade your magneto to `1.9` which contain all the patches.

Have a look https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/Security-Patch-SUPEE-6285-Error-Hunk-5-FAILED-at-1115/m-p/10156

Answer (score 0):

For fix that, is need to copy the theme "modern" from magento-1.9.0.1 to your magento actual version.

In my case this were issue.

*can't find file to patch at input line 894
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

### The text leading up to this was:

|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|index 43698c2..f4fe5ab 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
--------------------------*

On my case, just copy theme, solve the issue!
=)